# how to use "for" loop in R for non-consecutive observations

Tags: r, loops

I am still getting acquainted with R and I've found some small technicalities that I would really appreciate if someone could help me to solve them.

I am trying to write a loop using "for" for non-consecutive observations, so instead of a loop for a sequence from 1:1000 days I would like to run it for specific observations, let say, each 64 days

I tried defining a vector X with the sequence I want, but R returns an error and only uses the first numerical entrance of the vector.

X<-seq(from=1, to=1000, by=64)
for(i in 1:X){....

I hope someone can give me a hint how to do this

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Thank you Hugh, as simple enough as that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is

```
for( i in seq(from=1, to=1000, by=64) ) { print(i) }
```

`1:X` with try to create a vector from 1 to X stepping 1 at a time, and in this case X is a vector so it only takes the first element.